# SQL: WITH clause how to refer to column_name

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression

I will create some pseudo code to explain my problem:

```
WITH MAX_BES AS 
(SELECT MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID FROM TABLE1);

SELECT .....
FROM 
  TABLE2, TABLE3
WHERE
  TABLE2.ID IN (MAX_BES.MAX_ID);
```

The code above does not work. How should I reference a column from my WITH clause within an IN clause?

Thanks a lot for your quick feedback.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Your question is lacking of details. [Simply we are unable to help you in its current state...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Edit the answer to specify *at least*: What have you tried so far? What technologies/languages are you using? What database engine? Why it "does not work"? What are you trying to accomplish? What do you get *precisely*?

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-select and make that one statement, not two.

```
WITH max_bes AS (
  SELECT max(id) AS max_id 
  FROM table1
) --<< no ; here!
SELECT .....
FROM table2
  JOIN table3 ON ... ??
WHERE table2.id IN (SELECT max_id FROM max_bes);
```